# Distribution Certificate/Profile impact on Push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We already have on appstore, and push notification are working for that. Now we have to update app, but we don't have original distribution certificate/provisional profile. If we sign app with a new cert and profile and update on appstore, then will that impact push notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No impact on notification. You can generate new certificate if you don't have them make sure that you are generating properly as earlier.You may not need to generate .PEM file on server to send push notification as it is already on server.you can regenerate them as well just replace with new passphrase on server